# BSON | terminal and non-terminal

Tags: bson

Reading through the [BSON specification](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification) I came across the **terminal** and **non-terminal** terms in it. For example:

> Valid BSON data is represented by the document **non-terminal**.

<...>

> The following basic types are used as **terminals** in the rest of the grammar.

What do “terminal” and “non-terminal” mean in the context of the BSON specification?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In formal grammar, a *terminal symbol* is one that cannot be broken down further, e.g. a literal character or digit (but not necessarily as it depends on the grammar), a *non-terminal symbol* is a symbol that can be reduced further by the production rules (the rules that define the grammar) until it's reduced to a terminal symbol, for example, in the following grammar `integer` is a non-terminal symbol, `0-9` are terminal symbols.

```
<integer> ::= ['-'] <digit> {<digit>}  
<digit> ::= '0' | '1' | '2' | > '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9'
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_and_nonterminal_symbols