# Difference between terminal symbol and nonterminal symbol?

Tags: parsing, syntax, grammar

What's the difference between terminal & non-terminal symbols in system programming with examples?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BSON | terminal and non-terminal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13206423/bson-terminal-and-non-terminal)

Comment: Duplicate, with a much more substantive answer:  [What are terminal and nonterminal symbols?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57908662/what-are-terminal-and-nonterminal-symbols)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A terminal symbol represents a single element of the language, and a non-terminal symbol represents several elements.

> terminal and nonterminal symbols are the lexical elements used in
>   specifying the production rules constituting a formal grammar.
>   Terminal symbols are the elementary symbols of the language defined by
>   a formal grammar. Nonterminal symbols (or syntactic variables) are
>   replaced by groups of terminal symbols according to the production
>   rules.

source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_and_nonterminal_symbols